# Can we increase the size of python interpreter's stack frame facility?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the below code,

```
def squareroot(a):
    x = 1
    def apply(x):
        if x*x == a:
            return x
        else:
            return apply((x + a/x)/2)

result = squareroot(2)
print(result)
```

the following error is reported:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Do we have any 'option' to pass python interpreter which increases the size of stack frame before running this code?

Comment: Languages like C has separate stack segment which is limited in size. But "everything is an object" in python. For example `code`   `stack frames` are also stored as objects in python. I learnt objects are stored in heap area. Do we have any constraint to maintain limit for the depth of stackframes in heap?

Comment: Not answer to the question, but I would add "if (x + a/x)/2 == x: return x" to avoid infinite recursion

Comment: For the topic given in the title, see answers for the question hinted by @KasraAD. For this specific code I would recommend however to change to an iterative implementation (i.e. loop) - its not a problem _requiring_ recursion and also does not suggest this very strongly either (imho).